# How do I auto timestamp a sheet when something is moved to it

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I am using this function to automatically move a row to a secondary sheet when a set value is entered.

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Tracker";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 4; 
  var valueToWatch = "YES";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "30Day";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();


  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

What I want is to have an Automatic timestamp show up when it gets moved over. The problem is that all the functions I have found require you to go to the second sheet and manually change something in order for it to trigger. I want to trigger as the above script move the row over. Any help would save me a lot of time and beating my head against the wall.